# Header not staying in place

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've positioned the header of my page to be always at the top by using

```
  position:fixed;
```

This works perfectly fine, but not on Chrome on my android devices. The header get's pushed away by something and is placed where it shouldn't be: a few 100 pixels from the top instead of 0 pixels from the top.

My guess is that it's caused because of some javascript i'm using. The first piece of javascript is when a user presses an icon a menu shows up, this is the code:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#toggle').click(function(){
            $('div.showhide').toggle();

        });
    });
</script>
```

The second code is when a user scrolls away from the header the header closes:

```
    <script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 
      $(window).load(function(){
      $(window).scroll(function() {   $('.showhide').fadeOut("fast");
      });
      });//]]>  
    </script>
```

This is my page code:

```
<div class="showhide">
    <div class="menubg">
        <div class="menu">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="item">
                    <div class="img">
                        <a href="conv.cfm" style="color: white; text-decoration: none;"><img style="margin-top: 8px;"  src="img/conversations.png" alt="conversations" />
                    </div>
                    <p>Gesprekken</a></p>
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <div class="img">
                        <a href="home.cfm" style="color: white; text-decoration: none;">            <img src="img/high_res.png" alt="notifications" style="height: 38px; margin-left: 23px;" class="nav left" />
                    </div>
                    <p>Vrienden</a></p>
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <div class="img">
                        <a href="profile.cfm" style="color: white; text-decoration: none;"><img src="img/hoofd.png" alt="me" />
                    </div>
                    <p>Ik</a></p>
                </div>
                <div class="clear"></div>
                <div class="item">
                    <div class="img">
                        <img src="img/HC.gif" alt="reception" />
                    </div>
                    <p>Receptie</p>
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <div class="img">
                            <a href="settings.cfm" style="color: white; text-decoration: none;"><img src="img/wrench.gif" alt="settings" />
                    </div>
                    <p>Instellingen</p></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="headbg">
    <div class="header">
        <a href="#">
            <img src="img/conversations.png" alt="conversations" class="nav left" />
        </a>
        <a href="#">
            <img src="img/high_res.png" alt="notifications" style="height: 38px; margin-top: -1px;" class="nav left" />
        </a>
        <a href="#">
            <img src="img/habbobtn.png" alt="habbologo" class="nav right" id="toggle" />
        </a>
    </div>
</div>


<div class="content">
   </div>
   // Page continues after this but it isn't causing the problem
```

Forgot to add it, but this is my css code:

```
.menubg {
width: 100%;
background-color: #201d19;
}
  .menu {
width: 320px;
height: 190px;
margin: 0 auto;
overflow: hidden;
   }
  .showhide {
display: none;
   }
  .container {
width: 290px;
height: 160px;
background-color: #201c18;
border: 1px solid #282420;
border-radius: 5px;
position: absolute;
padding: 5px;
margin: 10px;
   }
   // This is not all the css, if it's needed i'll add it
```

If anyone could help me out with this problem i would appreciate it!

Comment: Please, use `jsFiddle.`

Comment: Try to set top:0; left:0; to your container.

Comment: Top:0; left: 0; didn't work for me. I've added my code to jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/uw2e2/1/

Comment: `position:absolute` does not keep the element on the viewport.  `Absolute` means that it is positioned relative to the first parent with a position other than static (default).  If no parent matches this, then it is positioned relative to the *document*.  `position:fixed` will position your element relative to the device's viewport (browser window).  However, both absolute and fixed are rendered outside the document flow, so you will have to add padding/margin to get the rest of your content to adjust for the spacing

Comment: My bad! It's fixed ofcourse. Changed the main post.

Answer (score 0):

I've created a sample [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/G5Nar/1/) with header and content div.

```
#header
{
position:fixed;
...
    top:0;
    left:0;
}
#content
{
margin-top:set your header height;
}
```